# Why source can only load one .R file

Tags: r

Here is the question.
There are several .R files in the work directory, say, A.R, B.R, C.R respectively.
Now I want to load all these function files. However, when I call:

```
source("A.R")
source("B.R")
source("C.R")
```

and then, when I use `lsf.str()` in the console. I get the result as:
C : function (xxxxx). Just the C.R file is sourced
What's more, I can not call function A and B. So, my question is how may I load all of the function files and save them in the global environment?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using the same function names in all the sourced files? Because you can call source as often as you like on as many different files as like. The results are basically the same as copying/pasting the contents of the file into your R session (but it's done so non-interactively)

Comment: if your sourcing them in a function and want them evaluated in the global invironment, you can use `source('A.R' ,local=.GlobalEnv)`

Comment: `help(source)` has an example at the end that shows how to load up all the `.R` files in a directory which could be easily adapted for custom needs.